# Add a part of URL in Iframe with javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

i want to add last part of url in iframe
suppose my url is http://myweb.com/123456/

i want to add 123456 in iframe like

`<iframe src ="http://myweb.com/demo.html?user=123456"></iframe>`

Please Help, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the solution. Purely using JavaScript no jQuery.

**Steps:**

- Extract `url`'s last part.
- Get the `iframe` element using it's `id`
- Get the current value of `src` attribute of `iframe`
- Append the concatenate the extracted last part of url to current value of `src`
- Update the attribute value

---

```js
var url = "http://example.com/12345";
var lastPart = url.split('/').pop();

console.log("Last part of url: " + lastPart);

var myIframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
var iframeSrc = myIframe.getAttribute("src");

console.log("Initial src value: " + myIframe.getAttribute("src"));

myIframe.setAttribute("src", iframeSrc + lastPart);

console.log("src after appending: " + myIframe.getAttribute("src"));
```

```html
<iframe id="myIframe" src ="https://example.com?user="></iframe>
```

Comment: You may want to mention the addition of an ID to the iframe tag. This is an addition to the OP's original implementation. Besides that this is certainly a good option though.

Comment: what if http://example.com/12345 is current page (parent page) url how to get it.

Comment: Use `var url = window.location.href`

Comment: Doesn't matter what the `url` is. Last part after the `/` will be popped. You might have made some mistake in your code. Share the code via [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Then split using `=` like this `url.split('=').pop();`

Comment: When you run `var url = window.location.href` on jsfiddle the url will be different. It doesn't have any `=`. Test it for your website where the url will have `=`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just the following to add any values you may need to the end of the src (***Note this is jQuery, so this may not be what you are interested in***):

```js
var value = "123456";
$('iframe').attr('src', $('iframe').attr('src') + value);
document.write("New URL: " + $('iframe').attr('src'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<iframe src ="http://myweb.com/demo.html?user="></iframe>
```